# Boolean error, in the First code but not in Second, Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

This code is showing the error. But we type it in a different way it runs. I am not getting it.
any one please help me why the second code isn't showing the error?

You can check the error by this link:

[image: 1]

```
def check_input():
    choice = 'wrong'
    digit = False
    
    while choice.isdigit() == False or digit == False:
        
        choice = input('Enter the value: ')
        
        if choice.isdigit() == False:
            print('Please enter the digit between 0 to 10')
            
        if choice.isdigit() == True:
            if int(choice) < 1 and int(choice) > 10:
                digit = False
            else:
                choice = True
                       
    return int(choice)
```

```
def check_input():
    choice = 'wrong'
    within_range = False
    acceptable_range = range(0,10)
    
    while choice.isdigit() == False or within_range == False:
        
        choice = input('Enter the value: ')
        
        if choice.isdigit() == False:
            print('Please enter the digit between 0 to 10')
            
        if choice.isdigit() == True:
            if int(choice) in acceptable_range:
                within_range = True
            else:
                within_range = False
 
    return int(choice)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first code has this line:

```
choice = True
```

which, when executed, makes `choice` a value of type `bool`. That's why, the next time `choice.isdigit()` is executed, and because `bool` objects really don't have an `isdigit` attribute, you get the error.

The second code doesn't do that, so you don't get the error.